# Refresh a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a combo box as you can see in the code that takes the values from a table.
So after I click ok the values of the table change. 
How can I see these new values to the compobox without to close and open the jframe ?
I made a lot of study today about java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater and othe staff but I can not make it work, I am new to java and to programing general.
So here is the code:

```
public class Compo extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{//start of class Compo 
//start of variables
private JComboBox<String> CompoBox;
private String array[];
private JButton okButton;
private JPanel panel;
//end of variables
public Compo ()
{//start of Compo method
  super("Example"); 
    panel=new JPanel(null);

   //table =  new String[3];
   array= new String[3];
   array[0]="alpha";
   array[1]="beta";
   array[2]="charlie";

   CompoBox= new JComboBox<>(array);
   CompoBox.setBounds(50, 70, 100, 20);
   panel.add(CompoBox);
   okButton=new JButton("ok");
   okButton.setBounds(50, 120, 70, 30);
   okButton.setActionCommand("ok");
   okButton.addActionListener(this);
   panel.add(okButton);
   add(panel);
   setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   setSize(200, 200);
   setVisible(true);


}//end of compo method
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {//start of actionperformed
    String testString=event.getActionCommand();
    if (testString.equals("ok"))
    {//start of if
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
             String sample= array[i];
             array[i]=sample+"aa";

        }
    }//end of if
}//end of aciton performed


}//end of class Compo
```

Comment: How can I imporve it in 3 days that I am subscribed here?

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: The problem now is that the button does its job for only the first click!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this should be the answer you are looking for, hope you'll accept it:

```
    if (testString.equals("ok")) {
        CompoBox.removeAllItems();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            String sample = array[i];
            CompoBox.addItem(sample + "aa");
        }
    }
```

btw. the generic comqo-pox is done like this:

```
CompoBox = new JComboBox<String>(array);
```

Comment: I will try it just write now!Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can either use the `addItem(...)` and `removeItem(...)` methods on the combobox directly or provide your own `ComboBoxModel` and change the data in that model.

Although I'd generally like to use the latter option (i.e. my own model), for your skill level I'd suggest starting with the add/remove methods first.

Later you might want to work on the default model (which is of class `DefaultComboBoxModel` and implements `MutableComboBoxModel`). Keep in mind though, that you'd need a cast and be sure you get a model of the correct type in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Finally it works with the code that is up.